# Camel nested choice and exceptions

Tags: exception, apache-camel

I have a Camel route in which I'm trying to process a file and then try to insert a row to a database based on whether the file processing was successful. I just add a property "processed" and set it to true if the processing was successful in the bean I called. Since I'm checking these conditions I have nested choice and otherwise statements and I just wanted to make sure my statements are properly written. This is the basic structure of my route:

```
from("file:/test")
      .choice()
      .when(header("CamelFileName").endsWith(".txt"))
            .bean(new ProcessFileBean())
            .choice()
            .when(exchangeProperty("processed").isEqualTo(true))
                  .to("sql: insert into table (id, file) values (1, file)")
      .otherwise()
            .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                   logger.info("File has not been processed");
            }
            });
```

Also, can I catch any exceptions from the route, for example during the database insert process and log them to a file?

Answer (score 3):

Yes the route should work using the route you have defined.

To catch exceptions use the **OnException** syntax to take some action based on a particular exception. For example `OnException(IOException.class).handled(true).to("error");`

You can also catch exceptions similar to the try catch in normal java. See here:
http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html